# How to pinpoint what's slowing down Android app

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm new to Android (and Java for that matter) development.  I thought I was doing well - I have an app that reads in XML files, parses into a SQLite database, pulls from the database to populate different site sections (scrollable lists of news items)...etc.  I'm using AsyncTasks for the importing process...etc.

BUT - my app takes FOREVER (15-25) seconds to load the first time, and ~10 seconds every time I switch sections (parses a single XML file into a SQLite database, and populates a listView).

Compared to the iPhone app, which takes 2-3 seconds to switch sections...

**TLDR:**
How do I determine what's causing my app to run slow?  Is there a thread monitor or something - some way to view what's taking so long other than just putting Log.d()'s throughout?

Comment: If you are using eclipse with the ADT plugin there should be a debug process... I haven't used it much. Also is the Android about as old as the iOS? iOS users tend to upgrade much faster than Android users (over all) But don't wonder why a 3 year old android isn't as fast as the latest iPhone

Comment: Russ - I appreciate your time, but your comment is completely irrelevant to this question (and doesn't make sense, as obviously the 2 apps aren't identical code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think traceView contains too much information, you can easily get lost.

My solution is just log the system time at three place in the code.

Before and after and center at the potiential slow code.

like binary search, next time, narrow it down step by step, then finally find the culprit code.

Comment: Thanks - this works great for my needs.  While Jeffery's answer is probably more in depth, and what some people need, for me this method worked in 30 seconds - as opposed to having to learn all that traceview confusion.

Comment: for this to work, you need to know where problem is before you find it. i suppose you will learn this the hard way, but there are going to be non-obvious reasons for the slowdowns in your app. traceview was specifically invented for this purpose, and you think that putting timers around blocks of code is a better way to go?

Answer (score 3):

check out [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html).

it's a very nice tool that allows you see where your app is spending time down to the method level. i can't do it justice in a description here. follow the link and take a look.

you can also look into [strictmode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), but this is more for figuring out why your app's UI is not responsive.

Comment: Any chance you could give some instructions?  That link has the most minimal instructions I've ever seen.  I got to the tools directory in my command prompt... but now I'm trying to following it's "Usage:" comment, and keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class..."

Comment: here's a page with detailed instructions. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html. sorry, but i'm not going to spend my time here trying to write better docs than google.

Comment: Sure would be nice if they made instructions you could actually follow instead of generalizations about how "one could go about using the code"...but this seems to be the answer... will just have to mess with it until something makes sense.  Thanks!  (+1 for now - will mark as answer if it's still best answer in a few days)